# PHPから呼び出されたpythonの出力結果がおかしくなる

Tags: python, php, python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

python2ではPHPファイルからURLを持ってきています。ソースコードはほぼ同じなのに下記でエラーが出力されるのがよくわかりません。わかる方宜しくお願い致します。

python1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

url = "https://laboratory.kazuuu.net/get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-using-python/"

driver.get(url)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"title")

print(elements[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

python1の出力結果

```
Pythonを使用し画像の幅と高さを取得する | Men of Letters（メン・オブ・レターズ） – 論理的思考/業務改善/プログラミング
```

python2

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("要素数が二つではありません。")

else:
    try:
        url = sys.argv[1]
        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

        driver.implicitly_wait(10) # second

        driver.get(url)

        elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"title")

        print(elements[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))

    except Exception as e:
        print("error:",e)
```

python2の出力結果

```
error: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 52: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: 単に例外オブジェクトの文字列だけだと情報量が少ないので、こちらの [traceback --- スタックトレースの表示または取得](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/traceback.html) を使って詳細を表示してみてはどうでしょう？ それとスクリプトの先頭に明示的にエンコーディングを指定してみてはどうでしょう？ [Python で文頭に記載する文字コードの「アレ」（なんちゃら UTF-8 みたいなやつ）の名称と仕様](https://qiita.com/KEINOS/items/6efc1147b917d7811b5b) 他にもこんな記事があるようです。[PHPからPythonを呼び出す方法](https://miyabikno-jobs.com/embed-php-python2/), [Pythonをコマンドラインで実行。全角文字（日本語）を引数にする場合の対処方法](https://blog.s-giken.net/313.html)